# what is the difference between setting minimum interval and settting fetch withExpirationDuration in Firebase remote config?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios) it is said that I have to set the setting for remote config like this

```
let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
```

I assume the code above is used to always fetch the data from remote (to avoid 12 hours waiting, for testing). but I also find the code below to fetch the value using expiration duration

```
    let fetchDuration: TimeInterval = 0

    remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: fetchDuration) { (status, error) in

        if let error = error {
            // show the error
        } else {
            // do something
        }

    }
```

what is the difference between these two ? which one is used for testing to avoid waiting 12 hours ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfig#fetchwithexpirationduration:completionhandler:) says this about `withExpirationDuration`:

> Override the (default or optionally set minimumFetchInterval property
>   in FIRRemoteConfigSettings) minimumFetchInterval for only the current
>   request, in seconds. Setting a value of 0 seconds will force a fetch
>   to the backend.

So it just overrides whatever you had in the settings.